# Date Format with hours, minutes and seconds in C3JS

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I try to run the following code to display dates with minutes and seconds, what am I missing here ?

The graph does not display and the X axis is not properly displayed.

Thank you

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            ['x', '2017-01-01 12:10:00', '2017-01-02 05:00:00', '2017-01-03 03:00:00', '2017-01-04 03:00:00',
            '2017-01-05 03:00:00.000',
            '2017-01-06 03:00:00.000'],
            ['data1', 0.5, 0.5, null, null, null, null],
            ['data2', null, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, null],
            ['data3', null, null, null, null, 0.5, 0.5],

        ],
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it today, it was simple, **xFormat** instead of **format** has also to be put in the **data**.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```